# Using array of strings to check for existence of nested property in hash

Tags: ruby

Consider an array of properties that could exist within a nested hash:

```
property_selector = ['component_styles', 'styles', 'background' ,'color']
```

With the following nested hashes being possibilites:

```
object_to_search_containing_property = {
    some_attr: 'blah',
    component_styles: {
        styles: {
            background: {
                color: 'fff'
            }
        }
    }
}

object_to_search_not_containing_property = {
    some_attr: 'blah',
    component_styles: {

    }
}
```

Might there be a way to iterate through `property_selector` to search through these objects checking each level of the property nesting?

Is there anything in Ruby that does something akin to:

```
property_selector.each do |property|
    object[property][next_property] ... [property.length - 1]
end
```

---

**Updates**

Apologies for not mentioning before but I am using Ruby version **2.2.3**.

Comment: ruby version please it is actually important for this question as the current answer suggests

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you on Ruby 2.3+? Try [`Hash#dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig):

```
object_to_search_containing_property.dig(*property_selector) # => "fff"
object_to_search_not_containing_property.dig(*property_selector) # => nil
```

The only bugaboo is that the elements of your property selector array are strings, but you're building your nested object with symbol keys. Define your property selector array like this instead for the above code to work:

```
property_selector = [:component_styles, :styles, :background, :color]
```

Or, if you don't have control over how that array is defined, you can transform it on the fly:

```
object.dig(*property_selector.map(&:to_sym))
```

Here's a portable method:

```
def dig(object, *keys)
  keys.each do |key|
    break unless object.respond_to?(:[])

    object = object[key]
  end

  object
end

dig(object_to_search_containing_property, *property_selector) # => "fff"
dig(object_to_search_not_containing_property, *property_selector) # => nil
```

The same caveat about the property selector array applies here as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what the downvote is for, since this answer is both well-written and correct.

Comment: I was thinking the same exact thing. However for the community's sake if you were to propose a backwards compatible option that would be even better.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using an earlier version of Ruby :( Regardless, this is a fantastic answer! Upvoted

Comment: That's a nice quickie implementation of `.dig`, but... it does not dig into arrays or ostructs. Just a thought...

Comment: @Phlip I changed the test condition to be a little more flexible, but I'm out of time here so if it still falls short I'll leave it to someone else to provide a truly portable replacement for Ruby 2.3+'s Hash#dig.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the way to get values of `property_selector` then [hashie gem](https://github.com/intridea/hashie) might be helpful. There are lots of things it can do so I encourage everyone to check it out. In this case [DeepFind](https://github.com/intridea/hashie#deepfind) extension could be used. Here is an example from docs:

```
require 'hashie'

user = {
  name: { first: 'Bob', last: 'Boberts' },
  groups: [
    { name: 'Rubyists' },
    { name: 'Open source enthusiasts' }
  ]
}

user.extend Hashie::Extensions::DeepFind

user.deep_find(:name)   #=> { first: 'Bob', last: 'Boberts' }
user.deep_detect(:name) #=> { first: 'Bob', last: 'Boberts' }

user.deep_find_all(:name) #=> [{ first: 'Bob', last: 'Boberts' }, 'Rubyists', 'Open source enthusiasts']
user.deep_select(:name)   #=> [{ first: 'Bob', last: 'Boberts' }, 'Rubyists', 'Open source enthusiasts']
```

It can search through any Enumerable contained within the hash for objects with the specified key.

And based on [.travis.yml](https://github.com/intridea/hashie/blob/master/.travis.yml) gem supports `mri >= 2.0.0`, `jruby-9.0.5.0` and `rbx-3`

Answer (score 0):

What I wrote here is wrong. If time permits I will correct it, but for now, pay no attention.

Comment: Instead of `instance_methods.include?` you can use `method_defined?`. Also, your implementation of `#dig` is not complete because it does not support nested arrays and ostructs (my original version did not either). I do like your use of `Array#reduce`!

Comment: @mwp, thanks for putting me on to `method_defined?`. I made the changes to my answer. I elaborated my explanation of why my custom `Hash#dig` is complete.